# C++: Check whether user has implemented std::numeric_limits<USERTYPE>::lowest() for his class

Tags: c++, numeric, limits

I have a library class which for correct functioning needs `numeric_limits<USERTYPE>::lowest()` to be implemented for the user's class `USERTYPE`. Requirement for `USERTYPE` is that it has an `operator<`.

Is there a recommended way to check whether the user has forgotten to implement "lowest()"?  Per default `lowest()` returns `USERTYPE()`, the default constructed value. Firstly, it might not have a default constructor. Secondly, it might be the wrong value.

I came up using a static assertion for `numeric_limits::is_specialized` to be `true`, since the default is `false`. But is there a more elegant solution?

Of course I can also add a runtime assertion to a function where I get passed keys, to check that none is smaller than "lowest()" says. I was just wondering if I can do it cleanly at compile time.

Comment: Whats wrong with a nice clear compiler error stating they forgot to foo the bar?  Also, instead of requiring they have an `operator <` why not take a comparison template type and default that to `std::less`.  That way they could pass a lambda/functor/function or just overload the operator.  Makes it more extensible.

Comment: Do you want to do this check at compile- or run-time?

Comment: @NathanOliver `to foo the bar` art.

Comment: i guess the only problematic case is when `USERTYPE` has a default constructor (i guess you meant default constructor, because no constructor at all would be a bit weird) but the default constructed value is not the correct `lowest()`. All other cases will just fail to compile without doing anything extra, no?

Comment: @Some programme dude: Yes at compile time.

Comment: @ user463035818  : Yes, when a default ctor is available, it would compile without warning.

Comment: @NathanOliver : Yes, that's true. The problem is only I want to be sure they implement "lowest()".

Comment: Do you only want to check that it is implemented, or also that it returns a correct value?

Comment: I think for a user defined type I have not many chances to check, maybe the only thing is adding runtime assertions to the class functions, to check "real" values passed into the functions against the value "lowest()" provides.   So I think I would be happy with "lowest() is implemented".

Comment: Someone sent me code using meta programming, but using std::void_t  from c++17, but I cannot find his message any more, and I cannot test it since my compiler does not support c++17:
    #include <type_traits>
    template <typename T, typename = void> struct has_lowest_v_impl : std::false_type {};
    template <typename T> struct has_lowest_v_impl<T,
         std::void_t<decltype(std::numeric_limits<K>::lowest())>> : std::true_type {};
    template <typename T> inline constexpr bool has_lowest_v = has_lowest_v_impl<T>::value;
    //    Use: if (has_lowest_v<MyKey>) ....